# Saving QUARTZ triggers in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, quartz-scheduler

I am having an issue with QUARTZ (2.1.3) saving triggers to MySQL under Spring (3.1.1). After some debugging, I figured out the flow as followings:

1. ScheduleFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet calls registerJobsAndTriggers during startup
2. this.transactionManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition())
3. DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(dataSource); (in LocalDataSourceJobStore class)
4. INSERT triggers and job details with the connection from step 3
5. DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, this.dataSource); (in LocalDataSourceJobStore)
6. this.transactionManager.commit(transactionStatus) (from step 1)
7. commit() calls triggerBeforeCompletion (in AbstractPlatFormTransactionManager)
8. triggerBeforeCompletion eventually calls connection.close() because referenceCount (in ConnectionHolder) is zero (changed from 1 to 0 by releaseConnection).
9. connection.close triggers a ROLLBACK, as shown in the log on MySQL side.

Here are my config info:

```
    <bean id="dataSource.dbcp" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">...</bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">...</bean>

<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="startupDelay" value="15" />
        <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext" />
        <property name="schedulerName" value="mySched" />
        <property name="jobFactory" ref="springBeanJobFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                    <ref bean="dummyTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="quartzProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">5</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">60000</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
<bean id="dummyTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">...</bean>
```

I have tried various config changes based research on QUARTZ/Spring/This site and not been to get the triggers to be saved in QRTZ tables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More Info:  I did more debugging and found the same config/code works on MYSQL 5.1.58-1ubuntu1, but not on MYSQL 5.5.20.  MYSQL generic log of both versions shows exactly same sequence:

Comment: SET autocommit=0, INSERT (into QUARTZ table) and then ROLLBACK.  Somehow, the updates are persisted for 5.1.58, but not for 5.5.20.  Is this a config issue for MYSQL?   Thanks

Comment: I figured out one important difference between 5.1.58 and 5.5.20 of MySQL: the default storage engine of 5.5.5+ is InnoDB. Earlier version has MyISAM as default, so AutoCommit is in effect always true and the ROLBACK from connection.close does not do anything. Is anyone using Spring/QUARTZ on MySQL 5.5.5+ to persist jobs?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this? I am facing the same issue, I am not able to store the trigger while my job is being saved as I configured my job to be durable.